# .NET 4.5.x not available anymore?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I just wanted to continue working on my project in VS 2013 and wondered why I could not use some methods I used before.
At first I thought that it was my fault and that I did something wrong so I msdn'ed the specific classes but MSDN said that all of these methods should be available.
My target framework was initially 4.5 and these methods were introduced in 4.5.
Then I looked at my project properties and noticed that 4.5 and 4.5.1 was not available anymore.
Restarted Visual Studio - still no 4.5.x, restarted computer - still no 4.5.x.

I downloaded the .NET 4.5 full installer from microsoft and tried to reinstall it but the installer says that I already have 4.5 or higher installed. Even after I tried to deinstall and reinstall it it still says that the 4.5 or higher is installed, even if my Installed applications list says that it is not installed.

I really don't know what happened. I worked on my project some hours ago with no problems on 4.5 and suddenly it was not available anymore!?

Has anyone of you an idea what could have happened?

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro and I'm using VS2013.

Edit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP does not show any version higher than v4.0. So I guess it is not installed or known to the system.

Comment: What kind of project are you using?

Comment: It is a WPF C# project.

Comment: Check that the project file is okay. I have the same setup and I see 4.5.1 when I create a new WPF/C# project.

Comment: I tried to create an entire new solution and the only .net version available at setup are 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4 :(

Comment: The reference assemblies are under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`, so you should check whether you can see `v4.5` and `v4.5.1` there. If not, you probably get a corrupt VS installation and should reinstall it.

Comment: 4.5 and 4.5.1 folders are there and there are some dlls in there. I think I'll reinstall VS guess it is much simpler than further investigation. I hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me not long ago when I was setting up my dev environment in a virtual machine for Windows 8 + VS 2012. It seems that it was caused by an unsuccessful VS installation. I solved it by uninstalling then re-installing VS 2012.